# What is up with lighter/washed out text?

Tags: support, markdown

Occasionally I'll open a question and find some of the text has been set to a lighter color than normal

i.e.

LIGHT:

[image: Light]

instead of DARK:

[image: Dark]

I can't find anywhere that explains what this means.

Comment: What's interesting about this example is the negative answer is at the top. Usually, it's at the bottom. In this case, because it's the accepted answer, it appears at the top regardless of the score.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Assuming that this refers to the colour of answer text, they are greyed out when their score is -3 or below to indicate that their content is not entirely reliable.

Answer (score 5):

Such answers have been downvoted by a significant amount (scoring -3 or more), and have been made lighter to de-emphasize them.