# For how long can we see an answer, after it's been deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is up with lighter/washed out text?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142319/what-is-up-with-lighter-washed-out-text)

I'm not sure if my example will be valid when I post this, but take [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11894115/best-way-to-handle-errors-on-a-php-page) for example, if you'll scroll all the way down - you might still be able to see a deleted answer. For how long does SO keep a deleted answer viewable ?

Comment: Your deleted answer? Or the greyed-out downvoted answer? We can see the latter because it's not deleted.

Comment: @Bart The greyed-out downvoted answer. If it's not deleted then why is it displayed like that ? or should I change my question ?

Comment: It is displayed like that (I believe) after 3 or more downvotes.

Comment: Not a duplicate, but [here's the FAQ on deleted posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/131713).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That answer (score -4) is not deleted but has a score of -3 or less. These answers are displayed lighter. 
This is done

> to indicate that their content is not entirely reliable

Deleted answers can only be seen by 10k+ Users.