# Why are certain answers faded?

Tags: support, answers, user-interface

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is up with lighter/washed out text?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142319/what-is-up-with-lighter-washed-out-text)

While searching Stack Overflow, I found a faded answer, as seen below. What does it mean?

> [image: Faded Answer]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Answers with a score of -3 or lower are faded to visually indicate that the community feels the answer in question is not of a high enough standard to warrant much attention.

Comment: Actually, it's -2

Comment: @azulflame: Any examples? I'm reasonably sure it's -3.

Comment: Personal experience, it's -2

Comment: @azulflame: Compare [How to replace all '0xa0' chars with a ' ' in a bunch of text files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5428844/5428869#5428869) with [Limit upload/download speed (in Python)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5888139/5888206#5888206). It's -3 or lower.

Comment: Never mind, it is -3. What's weird, is that I had a greyed-out answer with a vote of -2 a week ago, not it's not greyed out.

Comment: i had one answer which was -2 i downvoted it but it greyed out after some time..not immediately after i downvoted it..i think it affects the answer greyed out after some time..like this one on SO - http://stackoverflow.com/a/25092055/1793718

Comment: @Lucky: the graying out is not applied when you just voted it down (from -2 to -3); you'd have to reload the page to see this.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes but i re-visited the page after I downvoted it after 5mins..not sure if it is a browser cache problem..

Comment: Do you have any userscripts or other extensions installed? For example, I have http://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch installed and with that script the fading is disabled when you mouse over such a post. That may be confusing if you are not aware of the feature.

Comment: @MartijnPieters i have many user scripts and styles and extensions that changes style of pages installed in chrome..well may be that might be the reason. but anyway it got the answer greyed out after sometime without changing any extensions or any stylish scripts which means the extensions and scripts are not a problem..and those stylish scripts are for other social websites like FB, Twitter and GPlus.

Comment: @MartijnPieters just now i downvoted an answer from -2 to -3..just after refreshing it got greyed-out..http://stackoverflow.com/a/18778698/1793718